# Access SQL to capture all related relatives

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Access tables, one regarding persons and the other regarding relatives. The tables relation looks like this.

tbl_Person

| PersonID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Abraham | 12 |
| 1002 | Bill | 13 |
| 1003 | Catty | 14 |
| 1004 | Derby | 15 |

tbl_Relative

| RelativeID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Zack | 42 |
| 2002 | Yan | 43 |
| 2003 | Xavier | 44 |

tbl_Relation

| RelationID | PersonID | RelativeID | Relation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9999 | 2001 | 1001 | Father |
| 9998 | 2002 | 1002 | Aunt |
| 9997 | 2003 | 1003 | Uncle |
| 9996 | 2001 | 1004 | Father |

I would like to select a relative (or person) and have an SQL query find persons (or relatives).
E.g. If I select Yan (2002), the SQL query will discover Bill as the Person related to Yan.
Alternatively if I select Derby (1004), the query will discover Zack as the relative, as well as Abraham, who is also related to Zack.

In essence:
Search : Derby, query finds Zack (father) and Abraham
Search : Yan, query finds only Bill

I can join (union) the two tables to form a combined table, like

```
Select PersonID, Name, Age, "Person" as category From tbl_Person
UNION
Select RelativeID, Name, Age, "Relative" as category From tbl_Relative
```

Comment: Have you done any search for Access geneology database template? This is the hardest type of db to design and I have never done one but I don't think your schema is optimal. Surely relatives can be persons and persons can be relatives. What determines who goes in tbl_Persons?

Comment: The Person table is not meant to be exhaustive, so that's why there are rows in Relative table and the rows in two table won't mix (i.e. rows in relative table do not appear in person table).

Please don't think beyond the question, just look at the question "as is"

Comment: This looks like it should help - https://www.devhut.net/ms-access-genealogy-database/

Comment: Okay, then what happens when you apply filter criteria to the UNION query?